# radio button widget for Dexterity-based content types?

Tags: plone, dexterity

in Archetypes-based content types if a vocabulary used on a choice field has less than certain number of items (5, IIRC) the widget used is a radio button input instead of a select list.

in Dexterity-based content types there's no such behavior and the select list is always used.

is there any way to force a radio button input?

I tested the following but is not working and I can't find any documentation available:

```js
from z3c.form.browser.radio import RadioWidget

class IMyType(form.Schema):
    form.widget(my_field=RadioWidget)
    my_field = schema.Choice(
        title=_('My field'),
        vocabulary=my_choices,
        required=True,
    )
```

I'm using Plone 4.2 and plone.autoform 1.3.

Comment: What version of plone.autoform are you using? This should work if you have plone.autoform 1.4 and an autoform-enabled form. With earlier versions you need to specify RadioFieldWidget instead. SteveM has implemented an improved widget that chooses its format automatically like the Archetypes one, but it hasn't been merged yet.

Comment: it worked, thanks! please convert your comment into an answer so I can accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a custom widget like this in plone.autoform 1.4 and above.

In earlier versions of plone.autoform you need to specify a "field widget" (a callable that produces a widget when called) instead of a widget class. (plone.autoform 1.4 supports either one, and some other things covered in its documentation.) In this case you would use z3c.form.browser.radio.RadioFieldWidget.

Comment: thanks, I think the problem is that I was importing RadioWidget instead of RadioFieldWidget.